# Writing to a TensorArray error: "Could not read index"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have written some TensorFlow code for a toy problem, which uses the `tf.while_loop`. The loop writes to a `tf.TensorArray`. On the first iteration, I want to write `10` into the first element of the array. Then on subsequent iterations, I want to write `1 + (i-1)` into the `ith element`. So the final array should be something like: `[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, ...]`.

Here is my code for the case where there are just two iterations in the loop:

import tensorflow as tf

```
def loop_body(i, x):
    x = tf.cond(tf.equal(i, 0), lambda: x.write(i, 10), lambda: x.write(i, 1 + x.read(i-1)))
    i = tf.add(i, 1)
    return i, x

num_iterations = 2
iteration_num = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)
array = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32, size=num_iterations)
loop_condition = lambda iteration_num, predictions: tf.less(iteration_num, num_iterations)
_, loop_output = tf.while_loop(loop_condition, loop_body, [iteration_num, array])
loop_op = loop_output.stack()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
outputs = sess.run(loop_op)
print(outputs)
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

`Invalid argument: TensorArray TensorArray_0: Could not read index 0 twice because it was cleared after a previous read (perhaps try setting clear_after_read = false?).`

But I don't understand this error. I should only reading index 0 once, on the second loop of the iteration. On the first loop, I am not reading index 0, and I am just assigning 10 to the first element of the array.

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

First, explain that the error was actually caused by `stack()`. You are only reading index 0 once , on the second loop of the iteration. But the role of `stack()` was read 0 again. In other words, your `tf.while_loop` has been executed correctly. Let's look at the following steps.

```
# loop_op = loop_output.stack() #commented code

outputs = sess.run(loop_output.read(1)) #Modify code
print(outputs)

#print
11
```

You can see that 11 has been produced successfully. If you change it to `read(0)`, it will report the same error.

Then the way to solve the error is to set `clear_after_read=False`:

```
array = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32, size=num_iterations,clear_after_read=False)
```